# Border Layout setting component at EAST to cover full space at the right

Tags: java, border-layout

I have components placed in a border layout at CENTER , SOUTH and EAST. The problem is that default, the component at the SOUTH takes the whole bottom space. But dont want to let the south component to take the space of right panel too. Here is the image :- https://www.dropbox.com/s/8slbh7y88ri1lyn/Untitled.png It is possible by putting a border layout inside other border layout but I can't do that.

Comment: "but I can't do that" - why not?  It's the correct approach - put the CENTER and SOUTH components in a panel that is itself the CENTER of the top-level layout.

Comment: but according to the basic concept of borderlayout, the south component will occupy the whole space of the bottom area

Comment: That was precisely my point. Put the center and south components into a separate panel so the south component takes the width of _that panel_ rather than the width of the original container. See my answer for full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible by putting a border layout inside other border layout but I can't do that.

As I suggested in my comment this is in fact the correct way to go about this.

```
// assume "main" is your current top-level container
main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
main.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
JPanel leftColumn = new JPanel();
leftColumn.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
main.add(leftColumn, BorderLayout.CENTER);

leftColumn.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
leftColumn.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now there is no SOUTH component in the main layout, so the `rightPanel` will take up the full vertical space. The `bottomPanel` will take up the south area of the space allocated to the `leftColumn` and the `centerPanel` will get the remaining space at the top left.